# Pushing app to Heroku

Tags: heroku-toolbelt

When I push my app to heroku by ">>>git push heroku master" I have the problem below

[Pic of a console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO9sG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a buildpack set to the app. That's incorrect. Buildpacks need to point to GitHub repos. You could take out the buildpack with `heroku buildpacks:clear`.